# How to select a range based on the value in the first column

Tags: excel

I want to select and copy to a cell in another sheet the range with yellow headers (B-E) based on the location name (column A), after that do the same for column H.

So for Location A the selection range would be B1:E7, for location B would be B8:E13 etc.

After selected, copy it to another sheet (named like each location) in the next blank cell in column A.

After this, select column H, copy it and paste it in the corresponding sheet in column G

[image: table]

Comment: Apply a filter. Start a macro recording. Filter the list by column A in order to isolate your first group. Copy the range. Paste the range. Stop the recording. Press Alt+F8. Select the macro you've just recorded (probably Macro1). Click on Edit. Read the code and try to understand it. Play a little with it to see if you can obtain what you want. Get stuck. Post your code here and ask for help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this vba solution (Excel 365)

I turned the data into a table (Insert - table) and named it `tblOrders`

See comments in code for explanation

```vb
Sub copyLocations()

Dim lo As ListObject: Set lo = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)  '--> adjust this to your needs

Dim arrLocations As Variant
With Application.WorksheetFunction
    'return a unique array for location names
    arrLocations = Application.Transpose(.Unique(lo.ListColumns("Location").DataBodyRange))
End With

Dim i As Long, ws As Worksheet

For i = 1 To UBound(arrLocations)
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    With ws
        .Name = arrLocations(i)

        'write column names for 2nd, 3rd, 4th, 5th and 8th column
        .Range("A1").Formula2 = "=INDEX(tblOrders[#Headers],1,{2,3,4,5,8})"

        'Filter values according to locations name and return relevant columns only
        .Range("A2").Formula2 = "=LET(filteredValues,FILTER(tblOrders,tblOrders[Location]=""" & arrLocations(i) & """), " & _
                "INDEX(filteredValues,SEQUENCE(ROWS(filteredValues)),{2,3,4,5,8}))"
        
        'transform formula into fixed values
        With .Range("A1").CurrentRegion
            .Value = .Value
        End With
    End With
Next
End Sub
```